# How to tell if Geotools map is in Pan Mode (Pan Tool Active)

Tags: geotools

Looking for a way to figure out if the current selected tool is the pan tool, or for that matter any specific tool.

Answer (score 0):

In the Swing implementations inherited from `org.geotools.swing.AbstractMapPane` you may call `getCursorTool()` and check for the type of the returned value:

```
AbstractMapPane pane = ...
if (pane.getCursorTool() instanceof org.geotools.swing.tool.PanTool) {
  // pan tool active
}
```

In the current SWT implementation `org.geotools.swt.SwtMapPane` it's not possible. Inherit from this class and override `setCursorTool(CursorTool)` to store a reference to the current tool.